# Caching using Joomla + PHP using images stores in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Lets say I have a file called "getimage.php" to obtain an image all we need to do is `getimage.php?imgid=1`

My Server guy is warning me that pages with multiple images become very processor heavy. So would you suggest making a copies on the file server of theses image? and have a cron job delete files not being used after x amount of time?

or can I some how make 1 MYSQL query to obtain all the images? would this be less heavy then the getimage.php calling 1 SQL per image?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: generally recommended not to store images in the db

Comment: I think storeng the orignal in the db... and then somehow making a cached version of the image on the file server.. and that gets deleted if unused after "x" amount of time, is something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get all the images in one shot from the database. In any case, is there any reason on why you're storing images in the database? This move has its benefits but, on the other hand, it has its drawbacks.

The only huge advantage I personally see from storing images in the database is when these images are subject to permissions (e.g. some users can see those images, some can't).

Comment: it makes the site back-up alot easyer. less files, on the file server.  make its easyer to add a watermark to the images when needed so they cannot be obtained without a water mark in them cases.